# hover over image, appear a link

Tags: css, hover

HI there i have the following code but it doesnt work . It suppose to hover over image and get a link caption.

```
 $('ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    var image= $(this).find('img'),
        thumbnail = $(this).find('div');

    thumbnail.width(image.width());
    thumbnail.height(image.height());
    thumbnail.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
     var image= $(this).find('img'),
        thumbnail = $(this).find('div');

    thumbnail.width(image.width());
    thumbnail.height(image.height());
    thumbnail.fadeOut();
});
```

here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/wdAzE/3/

Comment: Why does your linked fiddle have lots of `thumb - container`? Is that supposed to do something? Also, if you click on the 'JS Lint' button, you'll see there's a syntax error.

Comment: `thumb-container` is an invalid variable name. The `-` treated as subtraction. Rename it to smth. else, i.e. `thumbContainer`

Comment: Hi, David, the code is part of my page, and basically i have few thumbnails pictures and they  are in that container. I want to hover over the image to get the caption over the image. I dont know what is wrong with JS, I dont see the error, but its not showing me the image as well

Comment: Zoltan still doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/wdAzE/3/

Comment: @ZoltanToth okay I want this http://jsfiddle.net/FW7SY/2/

Comment: I dont know how to apply that code to my code, specially Sine I have ul and li many other places in my code

Comment: What did you mean, you have other ul elements but you want that effect to be applied only to particular ones? Use IDs or classNames to limit the scope.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wdAzE/6/

Comment: @Zoltan Is there anyway to have the Image of the cat there and as soon as you hover the mouse over, have the word bzzz over on it with the white background?

Comment: @ZoltanToth what does this due ? #thumbs > li

Comment: The `#thumbs > li` selects only the first level children `li` elements of the `ul#thumbs` - so this animation won't be applied to any other `ul`-s on the page

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/wdAzE/7/ ?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for teaching me something new

Comment: @ZoltanToth Doest that work on IE?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19415/discussion-between-zoltan-toth-and-behzad-b)